# "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

how can i solve this type of error

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
con.Open();

Comment: check your connection string, permission, and sql config (allow remote connection with cred and integrated auth ect)

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what went wrong: it was not able to connect to the server as specified in your connection string. Check the hostname and port etc.

Comment: sorry i am not understanding your ans